# CheckedListBox no itera todos los elementos checked

Tags: c#, checkbox

Estoy trabajando en visual studio 2017 , agregue en un windows form el siguiente CheckedListBox

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que al recorrerlo con la siguiente funcion

```
string localidad = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            foreach (string i in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                fun.PedirInsumos(localidad, i);
            }
```

si estoy en debug con un breakpoint iteracion por iteracion si corre la funcion pedir insumos la cual hace un insert a una base de datos , pero si lo corro sin el breakpoint solo inserta una o dos iteraciones y las demas no

Comment: a que te refieres con "las demas no" ? porque estas iterando los elementos checkeados unicamente, sino marcas ninguno no itera nada

Comment: osea marco 6 checkboxes pero solamente me hace el insert de 1 o 2 , pero si lo hago paso por paso en el debuger si los hace todos los elementos checkeados

Comment: si a ese codigo lo pones en un bloque `try...catch` no recibes ningun mensaje de error ?

Comment: Excepción producida: 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' en System.Data.dll me aparecio eso , creo que los inserts son tan rapidos que no se alcanzan a hacer , le puse un sleep de miedo segundo pero aun asi no pasa y no quisiera hacer super lento el proceso

Comment: ok entonces hay un exception, recuerda visualizar la propiedad Message del Exception para ver la descripcion del problema. el sleep no tiene nada que ver y el tiempo tampoco, debes ver el mensaje del problema para conocer porque razon falla

Comment: Mi error era que por una llave junto con una validacion que existia , era como si fuera el mismo registro entonces obviaba los demas , y solo los que se insertaban en distinto segundo se registraba